# What if there is a name clash even after using namespace?

Tags: c++

We usually use namespaces to avoid name clashes in C++. But what if there are two different libraries which have a class, that has the same namespace name and class name? Is there a work around?

(PS: I am pretty sure, that its a rare scenario, I never faced it, just happened to cross my mind)

Comment: 0_o, sue the both library creators? xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might happen, but its not very likely to do you much damage.  Not only do the namespace names have to be exactly the same, you have to actually use both libraries.  Chances are, if they've named their namespaces in some reasonable way, their names will indicate their purpose -- even if there are two libraries that use `GenericXMLParser` as their namespace, and probably have some class names in common, do you really expect to be using them both on one project?

This does make certain namespace names a bad idea, such as `boost` or `Ogre`.  Anyone using those (except the original users) should expect their library to be unusable in many cases.  A less common name, like `Pie`, is probably going to be fine for by far most people in by far most cases.  If both libraries using `Pie` become widely used, one might have to change; in that case, the namespace renaming trick can be used to keep backwards compatibility with old code.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use something related to the company/group itself.
This way the collision is avoided.
It is highly unlikely that a profesional library would choose something trivial like `MyNamespace`.

It would be like `Company::Project::Module`.

This is even clearer in java where you have `org.apache etc`

Comment: The advantage of the Java scheme being that there's a central registry of name ownership. The C++ problem could arise even if everyone is being professional, if there are two organizations with more-or-less the same name in different countries. In Java they'd be `com.apple` and `uk.co.apple`, but in C++ you'd better just hope that they're aware of the issue before they both start releasing C++ libraries that use the namespace `apple`.

Comment: Personally, I don't subscribe to using names of long gone companies as namespace names: There is a better chance that a company disappears than that its code does as well: they are frequently disappearing because they are bought out by another company who wants to get hold of the code. The defense? Be creative and din't call

Comment: @DietmarKuhl:You have a point, but when you write code for a company it is proprietary of the company.So you can't just arbitrarily use conventions.There should be consistency within the same product line.

Comment: Sure, there is. I'm following the style used. However, my point is that using the company name when initially choosing a namespace name isn't the right thing in my opinion. For my own stuff I'm using a name with is change with a trivial use of sed.

Comment: @DietmarKuhl:May be for an experimental project or startup.Big companies usually put the company name somewhere in the namespace.I don't think it is wrong.IMO it enforces the idea of the software being "propietary".

Answer (score 0):

You can rename one of the namespace with

```
namespace <new> = <old>;
```

But that will only get you so far. Here is an example :

```
namespace aaa {
   int foo() { return 42; }
}

namespace zzz {
   int foo() { return -42; }
}

namespace bbb = aaa;

int main() {
    aaa::foo();         //Original namespace is still there
    bbb::foo();  //but it is also available with a new name
    zzz::foo();  //No clash, that's what namespaces are for
    return 0;
}
```

But since the rename is really just an alias, the `aaa` namespace stays. This code will get you a duplicate symbol error (no matter how deep it is buried in .h files) :

```
namespace aaa {
   int foo() { return 42; }
}

namespace aaa {
   int foo() { return -42; }
}
```

You can get around it somehow by wrapping the clashing namespace in your own namespace declaration, like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

namespace aaa {
   int foo() { return 42; }
}

namespace zzz {
#include "clash.h"
}

namespace aaa2 = zzz::aaa;

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", aaa::foo());   //Original works
    printf("%d\n", aaa2::foo());  //Non-clashing through alias
    printf("%d\n", zzz::aaa::foo());  //Non-clashing real name
    return 0;
}
```

But that solution too will work only in trivial code, because all the included files in `clash.h` will end up in the `zzz` namespace.

+I think renaming `std` is forbidden though, if only by common sense.

Comment: That doesn't help, you still can't link the two classes in the same executable.

Comment: @SteveJessop is right. The trick works as long as you don't need to link ;) I edited my answer.